# MeteorJs: WebStorm Cannot find my template

Tags: meteor, webstorm

Why can't webstorm find my template. e.g. `Template.templateName.onCreated`. Note that the templateName exists. It's just that I get squiggly lines on templateName saying unresolved variable. I know it does not give me any error but just a matter of perspective. I just don't want to see squiggly lines. Any help?

Comment: is your template defined in html file?

Comment: Yes. Template name is defined and no errors. Its just that webstorm is not acknowledging it. @anstarovoyt

Comment: does the html file have handlebars icon? https://www.axiomadev.ru/tinymce/uploads/images/handlebars.png

Comment: @anstarovoyt It has. The first 3 months of using webstorm it was able to find my template. This only happened when I changed something in the javsacript library language version. Cause I wanted the webstorm to be able to understand coffee script. But reverting back it didn't change anything. Right now its ECMAScript 6.

Comment: try file -> invalidate caches

Comment: @anstarovoyt still saying 'unresolved variable' and can't find my template.